# Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller Intermittent Ethernet Connection

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, atheros

I recently installed Linux on a spare desktop PC and am having an issue with its Ethernet Controller:

> Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e091]
> (rev 13)

> Kernel: 5.4.0-86-generic

I have tested with both Ubuntu 20.04 and Mint 20.2 with the exact same behavior on both.  The internet connection is intermittent, requiring me to repeatedly try to start downloads/refresh web-pages for them to successfully start/open. This often results in failed downloads since they time-out part-way through. I do not see this issue when dual-booting into Windows 7. I have also tried two different Ethernet cables for good measure.

I have attached an [Example Image of Network Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBQNb.png) from the system monitor, which shows the strangely regular start/stop of an example download.

Output of **sudo lshw -C network**:

```
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 13
   serial: 44:8a:5b:9f:67:05
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.1.12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:19 memory:f7100000-f713ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

I realize that this is not the only question on askbuntu about this type of controller, but the rest have not mentioned this specific issue and are significantly outdated. It sounds like the previously recommended solution for fixing driver issues was using a backport of the kernal, but the cited versions are old (~3.10) and this is apparently not recommended anymore.

Please let me know if there are any suggestions for what I can try next, and if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, but it's not ideal: replace the router with something else. The Orbi brand of router I was using does not interact well with Linux and Raspberry Pi devices, but replacing it with another brand caused the issues to disappear.